# getting count of players from mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get the amount of users who have `rank = player`

So far I tried `select count(*) as count_players from users where rank = player`

I'm not sure where the error is, if only in the tags and query is correct or I'm going about it completely wrong, thanks in advance for the advice!

table: [users]

| id | username | password | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | $2y$10$zYharAUmf36hVzkYUg87y.avY | player |
| 2 | jane | $2y$10$zYhajIUGU89887jhgUg87yKJ8G | admin |

COUNT_PLAYERS = 1

Comment: Please show your SQL table structure along with any errors you are getting.

Comment: `rank` is presumably a string value. You'd have to do `select count(*) as count_players from users where rank = 'player'`

Comment: Try using rank in count like count(rank)

Comment: @BipLob That isn't necessary. `count(*)` should work

Comment: even `count(1)` should work as well

Comment: thanks guys, i found the solution, it was: `select count(*) as count_players from users where `rank` = 'player'`

Comment: Yah, you are right but specifying a column and specific data is good practice.

Comment: @BipLob "is good practice" --- it's not: they are 2 semantically different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Cully below is right, it shouldn't need to be grouped when you're after a single result. You would do the following when you were after it grouped by rank (and you wouldn't do rank='player').

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_players FROM users WHERE rank='player';

OR SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_players FROM users GROUP BY rank if you wanted it grouped.

Have you tried quoting the rank you're targeting? It's a string, not a variable.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not necessary in this query.

Comment: Quite right, my mistake. I've fixed.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Xaraxia - but i am still getting same error